# Get the location of a variable in x86 assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86

In x86 assembly language, is it possible to determine the location of a variable in memory?

Here, I'm trying to find the location of X in memory, so that I can find the value that is stored at the address immediately after it.

```
.686p
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 2048

.data
X   byte         "1234"

ExitProcess proto, exitcode:dword
.code
start:

mov ah, X;
;now how can I obtain the location of X in memory?

invoke  ExitProcess, 0
end start ;what does the end statement do?
```

Comment: This question has a similar title, but doesn't appear to be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682778/x86-assembly-actually-get-a-variables-value-vs-using-its-memory-location

Comment: This Google search didn't give me many useful results, either: https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=assembly+language+get+location+of+variable+in+memory&oq=assembly+language+get+location+of+variable+in+memory&gs_l=hp.3...1036.17561.0.17836.82.74.8.0.0.1.591.6759.54j17j0j1j1j1.74.0.les%3B..7.0...1c.1.6.psy-ab.kBLR5fho0eU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43828540,d.dmg&fp=c88c58e01e24d8b1&biw=1366&bih=639

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `lea` instruction, something like:

```
lea edx, byte ptr x
```

Comment: What will this statement do, specifically?

Comment: Exactly what you asked for, get the address of the variable `x`. And then store it in `edx`. Come on, download the CPU manual, it's all there.